# Прошу совета по синтаксису решения async / await

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
function getRes(a,b) {                          
  $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: url,
   data: {val1: a, val2: b},                   
     success: function(data) {
       return data;
     }                                                                               
  });
}

(async function() {
 var res = await getRes(2,3);
   console.log(res); // undefined
 })();
```

Поставленная цель - добиться множественного использования `getRes()` разными частями кода не достигнута, результат `undefined`. Прошу подсказать, что я делаю неправильно и как это можно исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` в функции должен помочь

```js
function getRes(a, b) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: {
      val1: a,
      val2: b
    }
  });
}

(async function() {
  var res = await getRes(2, 3);
  console.log(res); // undefined
})();
```

Comment: Эм.. Возвращаемый jQuery объект точно совместим с промисом и применим в await? Он же не промис возвращает.

Comment: На радостях не заметил, спасибо! :)

Comment: Хм.. Похоже и правда работает :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) возвращает [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) а он `thenable` так что все ок должно быть

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRes(a,b) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: url,
      data: {val1: a, val2: b},                   
      success: resolve,
      error: reject,
    });
  })
}

(async function() {
  var res = await getRes(2,3);
  console.log(res);
})();
```